# How to format NodaTime date string globally in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: nodatime, asp.net-core-2.1, json-serialization

Currently, I am trying to use the `JsonFormatters` for serializing a string in `ISO 8601` spec. format in my startup config, but could not get it to work.

My Startup Config is as follows:

```
services.AddMvcCore(
    (options) => {
        options.SslPort = 44321;
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    }
)
.AddJsonFormatters(jsonSerializerSettings => {
    jsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
    jsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ";
})
.AddApiExplorer()
.AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = false;
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
.AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

I also tried [ServiceStackText](https://github.com/AnthonyCarl/NodaTime.Serialization.ServiceStackText/blob/master/README.md) which is mentioned in the [documentation](https://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/serialization), but that did not work either.

```
 NodaSerializerDefinitions.LocalTimeSerializer.ConfigureSerializer();
 DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb
     .CreateDefaultSerializersForNodaTime()
     .ConfigureSerializersForNodaTime();
```

I keep getting the following format,

i.e. for `LocalDate` serialization:

```
{
    "patientDob": "Thursday, June 15, 2017",
}
```

How can I configure the string `ISO 8601` spec. formatting for `NodaTime` date types globally?

my model,

```
{
    public LocalDate patientDob { get; set; }
}
```

and my view model/API resource:

```
{
    public string patientDob { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `NodaSerializerDefinitions`? I don't see anything in the code you've provided which calls the regular NodaTime  JSON.NET extension method `ConfigureForNodaTime()` - I'd expect that to be in the `AddJsonFormatters` call: `.AddJsonFormatters(settings => settings.ConfigureForNodaTime())`

Comment: @JonSkeet, adding `                    jsonSerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime (DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb); to `AddJsonFormatters` does not affect the formatting either 
`

Comment: That surprises me. Could you provide a simple way of reproducing this? I would really expect that to work, assuming you haven't got other code that changes the JSON formatter away from Json.NET.

Comment: @JonSkeet I reproduced it [here](https://github.com/embryologist/NodaTest)

Comment: This question is a good example of why it's useful to provide a [mcve] from the start. The question gives the impression that you're converting an object containing a `LocalDate` into JSON, but you're not - you're converting your resource that only has a `string`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the problem, in your controller:

```
res.NodaLocalDateString = apiResource.NodaLocalDate = nodaModel.NodaLocalDate.ToString ();
```

You're not converting a `LocalDate` into JSON at all; you're converting a *string* into JSON, and you're obtaining that string by calling `LocalDate.ToString()`.

Change your API resource to have a `LocalDate` property instead of a `string` property, so that the conversion is done by Json.NET instead of by you calling `ToString()`.

Comment: sorry to mislead you with my old post, I am aware of the conversion to string effect, my question. my original question was about if its possible to have this string conversion format output comparable with the thread culture globally rather than the need to do it locally to each variable?

Comment: @JSON: Do you mean your question isn't actually about JSON at all? I'm finding it really hard to understand what you're actually trying to achieve. (I also don't know why you want your View/API model to have a string representation rather than just the Noda Time representation.) As far as I can tell I've answered this question - I suggest you ask a *new* question, trying to be as clear as you possibly can about what you're trying to achieve and why.